# build geoserver with maven offline

Tags: maven, geoserver

Can anyone tell me how to build a java application (geoserver in this case) with maven in no-internet-connection envrionment? I can access the internet from another environment from which I can download dependencies. But I have not found any document on how to download geoserver dependencies (POM or jar files?) from where and into where (a local repository?), and how to use maven to access repository and build geoserver offline. Thank you.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. You should be more specific and include the following: What you have done, what issues you are running in to, and what the specific desired end result is.

Comment: Run the build on a connected server, then copy the repo directory to your offline server, then run maven with the -o switch.

Comment: I assume you can't test it offline anyway :) use -o to run maven in offline mode. Also, you can use mvn dependency:go-offline to load all imagined dependencies

Comment: Thanks for all the replys :). I think I need to be a bit more specific about my problem:

Comment: I think I need to be a bit more specific about my problem. I have a VM machine which has geoserver source code and maven installed. I want to build geoserver so that I can debug it with eclipse. But this VM machine can not connect to internet directly. So I tried to build it with maven offline switch: mvn -o clean install. but I have the following error:

Comment: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav:jar:1.0-beta-2 is missing, no dependency information available
$ mvn -o clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav:jar:1.0-beta-2 is missing, no dependency information available
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

Comment: I guess I need to setup the repo directory, but I don't know how to setup the repo directory and how to obtain the missing POM or jar file from where.

Answer (score 1):

Set M2_REPO path in eclipse. Go to Preference > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variable > click New and add M2_REPO and give path of m2 repositry inside user.